# Need a new laptop that meets the following requirements

Tags: laptop, development

I'm looking to buy a new laptop used mainly for heavy programming and needs to be able to play HD videos without trouble.

As far as I was able to find (and I'm open to better suggestions), I have the following requirements:

- Budget: ~$1000
- intel i5 CPU (HQ vs U? what do i really need?)
- display: 15+ in; Full HD (1920x1080)
- RAM: 8+ GB
- Storage: 1 TB HDD

One important thing to add is that I already have a 250 GB SSD that i would like to install in the new laptop (SSD where the HDD is, and the HDD + adapter instead of the DVD drive, for example). Any recommendations are welcome.

I just don't know much about these things so I can't make an educated decision.
Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: What are your expectations as to battery life? What software do you use for programming?

Comment: Eclipse, android studio, visual studio. As for battery life... Open to suggestions and not too much picky

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is "Programming."  This can have a range of expectation from writing code that gets executed on another server (like a web app) to data modelling, to app development that needs virtualized machines.

With the price point you specified, I would go with....

- any MacBook Pro from 2010 through 2013 if you like OS X or Sierra.  It will run Windows 10, but I wouldn't spend Apple money on a Windows machine
- A [Dell XPS 15](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-15-9550-laptop/pd?ref=PD_OC) if you want excellent portability, excellent graphics and a reliable machine
- A [Dell Inspiron 5000 Series](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/inspiron-15-7579-2-in-1-laptop/pd?ref=PD_Family) if you want great value and a 2-in-1.

Comment: Ideally, you should split this answer up into one answer per recommendation with some detail about the product, so that they can be voted on individually.

Comment: I will be developing apps and using virtualized machines. What about the processors and my shuffle of drives?